# Inno set up installer not restarting application after installation is complete

Tags: inno-setup

I am calling an installer generated with Inno Setup 6.1 in command line with the SILENT and RESTARTAPPLICATIONS flags. The installation works fine but the application does not restart after despite the RESTARTAPPLICATIONS flag.

At the end of the log it is written "Attempting to restart applications." but it does not seem to work.

Any idea ?

Here is the log :

```
2020-11-28 19:09:06.807   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
2020-11-28 19:09:06.807   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.1.2
2020-11-28 19:09:06.807   Original Setup EXE: \\nt-nas\Applications\Installeurs Jenkins\SkinCamConfig\2020-11-28-15h53 - SkinCamConfig - installer.exe
2020-11-28 19:09:06.807   Setup command line: /SL5="$5B12B2,8955790,780800,\\nt-nas\Applications\Installeurs Jenkins\SkinCamConfig\2020-11-28-15h53 - SkinCamConfig - installer.exe" /SPAWNWND=$3E0F0E /NOTIFYWND=$110EDC /SILENT /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOG="D:\Work\Projets\log.txt"
2020-11-28 19:09:06.808   Compatibility mode: Yes (Installer)
2020-11-28 19:09:06.808   Windows version: 10.0.19041  (NT platform: Yes)
2020-11-28 19:09:06.808   64-bit Windows: Yes
2020-11-28 19:09:06.808   Processor architecture: x64
2020-11-28 19:09:06.808   User privileges: Administrative
2020-11-28 19:09:06.809   Administrative install mode: Yes
2020-11-28 19:09:06.809   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2020-11-28 19:09:06.809   64-bit install mode: Yes
2020-11-28 19:09:06.813   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Temp\is-HFKAL.tmp
2020-11-28 19:09:06.975   Found 14 files to register with RestartManager.
2020-11-28 19:09:06.975   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2020-11-28 19:09:07.582   RmGetList finished successfully.
2020-11-28 19:09:07.582   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: SkinCamConfig.exe
2020-11-28 19:09:07.582   Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? Yes (0)
2020-11-28 19:09:07.616   Starting the installation process.
2020-11-28 19:09:07.622   Shutting down applications using our files.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.147   Setting permissions on directory: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\Log
2020-11-28 19:09:08.147   Starting 64-bit helper process.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.164   Helper process PID: 22772
2020-11-28 19:09:08.192   Setting permissions on directory: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\Template
2020-11-28 19:09:08.193   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig
2020-11-28 19:09:08.198   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\unins000.dat
2020-11-28 19:09:08.200   -- File entry --
2020-11-28 19:09:08.201   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\unins000.exe
2020-11-28 19:09:08.201   Non-default bitness: 32-bit
2020-11-28 19:09:08.202   Time stamp of our file: 2020-11-28 19:09:06.524
2020-11-28 19:09:08.202   Dest file exists.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.202   Time stamp of existing file: 2020-11-28 18:51:24.393
2020-11-28 19:09:08.202   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2020-11-28 19:09:08.203   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2020-11-28 19:09:08.203   Installing the file.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.219   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   -- File entry --
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\SkinCamConfig.exe
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   Time stamp of our file: 2020-11-28 15:53:56.000
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   Dest file exists.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   Time stamp of existing file: 2020-11-28 15:53:56.000
2020-11-28 19:09:08.220   Installing the file.
2020-11-28 19:09:08.279   Successfully installed the file.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.229   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 19:09:09.229   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SkinCamConfig\SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 19:09:09.230   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.260   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.328   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 19:09:09.328   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SkinCamConfig\Désinstaller SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 19:09:09.331   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.334   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.395   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 19:09:09.396   Dest filename: C:\Users\Marie\Desktop\SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 19:09:09.397   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.399   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.548   Saving uninstall information.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.548   Renaming uninstaller.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.549   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 64-bit install.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.549   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SkinCamConfig_is1
2020-11-28 19:09:09.549   Writing uninstall key values.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.550   Detected previous non administrative install? No
2020-11-28 19:09:09.550   Detected previous administrative 32-bit install? No
2020-11-28 19:09:09.552   Installation process succeeded.
2020-11-28 19:09:09.558   Attempting to restart applications.
2020-11-28 19:09:10.017   Need to restart Windows? No
2020-11-28 19:09:10.021   Deinitializing Setup.
2020-11-28 19:09:10.024   Stopping 64-bit helper process. (PID: 22772)
2020-11-28 19:09:10.026   Helper process exited.
2020-11-28 19:09:10.035   Log closed.
```

Here is the log when I remove the SILENT flag :

```
2020-11-28 20:40:43.444   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
2020-11-28 20:40:43.444   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.1.2
2020-11-28 20:40:43.444   Original Setup EXE: \\nt-nas\Applications\Installeurs Jenkins\SkinCamConfig\2020-11-28-15h53 - SkinCamConfig - installer.exe
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   Setup command line: /SL5="$2115F8,8955790,780800,\\nt-nas\Applications\Installeurs Jenkins\SkinCamConfig\2020-11-28-15h53 - SkinCamConfig - installer.exe" /SPAWNWND=$151594 /NOTIFYWND=$141492 /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /LOG="D:\Work\Projets\log.txt"
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   Compatibility mode: Yes (Installer)
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   Windows version: 10.0.19041  (NT platform: Yes)
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   64-bit Windows: Yes
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   Processor architecture: x64
2020-11-28 20:40:43.445   User privileges: Administrative
2020-11-28 20:40:43.446   Administrative install mode: Yes
2020-11-28 20:40:43.446   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2020-11-28 20:40:43.446   64-bit install mode: Yes
2020-11-28 20:40:43.449   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Marie\AppData\Local\Temp\is-553PG.tmp
2020-11-28 20:40:46.316   Found 14 files to register with RestartManager.
2020-11-28 20:40:46.316   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2020-11-28 20:40:46.830   RmGetList finished successfully.
2020-11-28 20:40:46.830   RestartManager found an application using one of our files: SkinCamConfig.exe
2020-11-28 20:40:46.830   Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? Yes (0)
2020-11-28 20:40:50.877   Starting the installation process.
2020-11-28 20:40:50.879   Shutting down applications using our files.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.416   Setting permissions on directory: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\Log
2020-11-28 20:40:51.416   Starting 64-bit helper process.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.434   Helper process PID: 19380
2020-11-28 20:40:51.457   Setting permissions on directory: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\Template
2020-11-28 20:40:51.459   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig
2020-11-28 20:40:51.464   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\unins000.dat
2020-11-28 20:40:51.465   -- File entry --
2020-11-28 20:40:51.466   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\unins000.exe
2020-11-28 20:40:51.466   Non-default bitness: 32-bit
2020-11-28 20:40:51.467   Time stamp of our file: 2020-11-28 20:40:43.174
2020-11-28 20:40:51.467   Dest file exists.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.467   Time stamp of existing file: 2020-11-28 20:10:22.948
2020-11-28 20:40:51.467   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2020-11-28 20:40:51.468   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2020-11-28 20:40:51.468   Installing the file.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.481   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.482   -- File entry --
2020-11-28 20:40:51.482   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\SkinCamConfig.exe
2020-11-28 20:40:51.483   Time stamp of our file: 2020-11-28 15:53:56.000
2020-11-28 20:40:51.483   Dest file exists.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.483   Time stamp of existing file: 2020-11-28 15:53:56.000
2020-11-28 20:40:51.483   Installing the file.
2020-11-28 20:40:51.543   Successfully installed the file.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.433   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 20:40:52.433   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SkinCamConfig\SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 20:40:52.434   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.464   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.619   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 20:40:52.619   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\SkinCamConfig\Désinstaller SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 20:40:52.621   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.625   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.867   -- Icon entry --
2020-11-28 20:40:52.867   Dest filename: C:\Users\Marie\Desktop\SkinCamConfig.lnk
2020-11-28 20:40:52.868   Creating the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:52.871   Successfully created the icon.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.075   Saving uninstall information.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.075   Renaming uninstaller.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.076   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 64-bit install.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.077   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SkinCamConfig_is1
2020-11-28 20:40:53.077   Writing uninstall key values.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.078   Detected previous non administrative install? No
2020-11-28 20:40:53.078   Detected previous administrative 32-bit install? No
2020-11-28 20:40:53.080   Installation process succeeded.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.084   Attempting to restart applications.
2020-11-28 20:40:53.526   Need to restart Windows? No
2020-11-28 20:45:50.317   -- Run entry --
2020-11-28 20:45:50.317   Run as: Original user
2020-11-28 20:45:50.317   Type: Exec
2020-11-28 20:45:50.317   Filename: C:\Program Files\SkinCamConfig\SkinCamConfig.exe
2020-11-28 20:45:50.395   Deinitializing Setup.
2020-11-28 20:45:50.398   Stopping 64-bit helper process. (PID: 19380)
2020-11-28 20:45:50.400   Helper process exited.
2020-11-28 20:45:50.431   Log closed.
```

Here is the message box that is displayed when the SILENT flag is off : [messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fID6f.png)

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I remove the /SILENT switch, the message box asking to launch the application is displayed (default is yes). The application is well launched if I choose to do so.

Comment: OK I thought that was the same thing as the installer is actually closing this application before the installation. Do you know if there is a way to automatically start the application when is SILENT flag is on ?

Comment: You're right, there was a skipifsilent option of the run section, I removed it and this is working now :) Thank you !

Comment: Do not forget to upvote the linked question and its answer.